# How to gradually erase the path traced by turtle in python?

Tags: python, graphics, turtle-graphics

I have been making some programs using python turtle in which I want to see path traced by turtle.I know that `turtle.penup()` makes the turtle lift up and `turtle.clear()` clears  the everything, but it is not what I want, I want the path traced by turtle to fade gradually until it just gets erased, So is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the path traced by turtle to fade gradually until it just gets
>   erased, So is there any way I can achieve this?

There's nothing built-in to turtle to support this.  Below is my crude emulation of gradual fade using lots of turtles and timers:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

PEN_WIDTH = 5
SEGMENTS_PER_LINE = 12
MILLISECONDS_PER_FADE = 500
AMOUNT_PER_FADE = 0.05

def fade_forward(t, distance):
    stride = delta = distance / SEGMENTS_PER_LINE
    heading = t.heading()

    while stride < distance:
        position = t.position()
        t.forward(delta)

        fader = faders.pop() if faders else fader_prototype.clone()
        fader.setheading(heading)
        fade(fader, position, delta)

        t.clear()
        stride += delta

def fade(f, position, distance, shade=0.0):
    screen.tracer(False)
    f.clear()

    if shade < 1.0:
        f.pencolor(shade, shade, shade)
        f.setposition(position)
        f.pendown()
        f.forward(distance)
        f.penup()

        shade += AMOUNT_PER_FADE
        screen.ontimer(lambda: fade(f, position, distance, shade), MILLISECONDS_PER_FADE)
    else:
        faders.append(f)

    screen.tracer(True)

faders = []

screen = Screen()

fader_prototype = Turtle()
fader_prototype.hideturtle()
fader_prototype.speed('fastest')
fader_prototype.width(PEN_WIDTH)
fader_prototype.penup()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.shape('turtle')
turtle.width(PEN_WIDTH)
turtle.penup()
turtle.setposition(-170, -125)
turtle.pendown()

for _ in range(10):
    fade_forward(turtle, 340)
    turtle.left(126)
    fade_forward(turtle, 400)
    turtle.left(126)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this, from the turtledemo source code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, mainloop
from time import perf_counter, sleep

def mn_eck(p, ne,sz):
    turtlelist = [p]
    #create ne-1 additional turtles
    for i in range(1,ne):
        q = p.clone()
        q.rt(360.0/ne)
        turtlelist.append(q)
        p = q
    for i in range(ne):
        c = abs(ne/2.0-i)/(ne*.7)
        # let those ne turtles make a step
        # in parallel:
        for t in turtlelist:
            t.rt(360./ne)
            t.pencolor(1-c,0,c)
            t.fd(sz)

def main():
    s = Screen()
    s.bgcolor("black")
    p=Turtle()
    p.speed(0)
    p.hideturtle()
    p.pencolor("red")
    p.pensize(3)

    s.tracer(36,0)

    at = perf_counter()
    mn_eck(p, 36, 19)
    et = perf_counter()
    z1 = et-at

    sleep(1)

    at = perf_counter()
    while any([t.undobufferentries() for t in s.turtles()]):
        for t in s.turtles():
            t.undo()
    et = perf_counter()
    return "runtime: %.3f sec" % (z1+et-at)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    msg = main()
    print(msg)
    mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! and it would be awesome if you can tell a bit about what is that ```while any([t.undobufferentries() for t in s.turtles()]):```.

Comment: The any() function returns True if any element of an iterable is True. If not, any() returns False. That means, we will jump out of the while loop as soon as the elements of the list empties out.