# Create transparent square in python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, transparent, fade, square

Using python turtle, I have made a code that connects points based on weather (high = X, low = Y) and the line between the points shows the weather that day (yellow = sunny). I previously tried to make the tail fade as the line continued. After asking people with more experience and scouring the web, I moved on from that option.

I then decided to try to create a transparent square that will overlay over the code periodically to create the same effect but I am having trouble finding how to do that. I need it to fade into the black background. Please let me know if anyone knows how to do this! Thanks!

Comment: Going back to your original "make the tail fade as the line continued" idea, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61963479/5771269)

Comment: Yes, I was looking at that but I couldn't figure out how to implement it into my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `setfillopacity` function to make it transparent:

```
# 50% 
setfillopacity(50)
```